# CSS issue in Edge - underline

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, sass, microsoft-edge

I have short scss. Links during `hover` have underlines, but not pseudo-elements `before` and `after`. This works everywhere, escept Edge/IE11. Any idea why?

```
a {
    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
      &::before,
      &::after {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this thread helps you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018420/ie-remove-underline-on-pseudo-element

Comment: Great, that helps a lot. Thank you @LeonLüttger !

Comment: @Jakub, Is your issue solved? If yes, I suggest you to post your solution here and try to mark it as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in similar kind of issues in future. If your issue is still persist than try to provide the current status of your issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of community I found solution to my problem. Edge/IE won't set value `none` to pseudo-element atribute if it wasn't declared before. So working example is:

```
a {
    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;

      &::before,
      &::after {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      &::before,
      &::after {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
   }
}
```